# Asp.net MVC 3 view engine error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, application-error

I am trying for custom error handling at global level in Application_Error.

```
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
    Server.ClearError();
    AssortmentDefinitionLogManager.LogException(ex);
    Context.RewritePath("/Error/Error");
    IHttpHandler httpHandler = new MvcHttpHandler();
    httpHandler.ProcessRequest(Context);
```

But i get this error

```
Error Message - The view '~/Views/Shared/Error' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.
```

I have also tried this

```
        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
        var redirectUrl = urlHelper.Action("Error", "Error");

        Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
```

Comment: Does the view "Error" exist in the ~/Views/Shared/ or ~/Views/Error/  directory?

Answer (score 0):

create a controller called `ErrorController` and inside this controller create an action method called `Error` which returns an ActionResult (or ViewResult).

Then create a view under `~/Views/Error/` called `error.cshtml`.

This will solve your problem.